# CORS blocking post requests - react and node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, backend, nodemailer

I am a beginner in server side programming. Trying to write code that will allow me to get data from state variable, send it to my backend and use nodemailer service to send it to an email adress. My frontend is as follows :

```
const handleSubmit = async () => {
    try {
      await axios.post(
        "http://localhost:2525/send_mail",
        {
          state
        }
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

state gets sent to backend :

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
require('dotenv').config();     

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cors());
app.options('',cors());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Server is running');
});

app.post("/send_mail", cors(), async (req, res) => {
    let { state } = req.body;
    const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
            user: 'adress@mail.com',
            pass:'password'
        }
    });
    await transport.sendMail({
        from: '<myemail.@example.com>',
        to: "reciever@example.com", 
        subject: "test email",
        html: `<div><p>${state.Message}</p></div>`
    });
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 2525, () => { console.log("Server is running"); });
```

If it matters, state is an object that gets filled from form data, it looks something like :

```
  const data = {
    FirstName: "",
    LastName: "",
    Message:"",
  };
```

When i visit port 2525, server is indeed running with the message i gave it. But when i try to submit my form with "handleSubmit", i get the following console error:
*>

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:2525/send_mail. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).*

And it **crashes the server**

As you can see i am already using cors middleware to try to handle it.

I tried adding a proxy to the package.json file, as : "proxy": "http://localhost:2525", ( i did not change anything else when i did that, i don't know if that is the correct way). This did not solve anything, but at least the server did not crash any more. Instead, the POST request gets a 404:
*

> POSThttp://localhost:2525/send_mail Referrer Policystrict-origin-when-cross-origin*

I tried running it in Chrome, same problem. I tried everything i could read on stackoverfrlow google or chat gpt, really that is cors-related. Even checked if port is maybe taken by something else in windows, checked that in cmd. Im at my wits end really

Comment: When a node process crashes (possibly with some sort of unhandled exception) it typically prints out some error message. Mind to share that error? But if the preflight (ie OPTIONS) request crashes the server, obviously, all browsers will give a CORS error. `app.options('', cors())` seems a bit strange to me (and it's not required if you already use `app.use(cors())`. I actually don't know, what express does on an empty route. And furthermore `cors()` is a middleware, that does not for itself send any response. So your `OPTIONS` request from the client may actually never return.

Comment: Thank you for the resposne, yes i get a terminal error :
node:internal/process/promises:289
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise 
*/);
            ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:587
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1284:16) {
  errno: -4078,
  code: 'ESOCKET',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '::1',
  port: 587,
  command: 'CONN'
}

Comment: That error tells you, the Mailserver you are trying to connect to on the server isn't available. But that isn't the cause of your cors issues. Remove that `app.options(''...)` thing and see if your cors request now succeeds.

Comment: Sorry, i should have clarified, i already tried without that. It still gives the same error.

Comment: What happens when you remove the *middleware* `cors()` call as second argument from your `app.post()` request? Since you are already executing `cors()` for all incoming requests and all routes, there's no need for double calls of same middleware.

Comment: The errors and the code don't add up. Your server is crashing with an error when trying to connect to a *local* SMTP server (`::1:587`) yet, there is no sign of that in your code. I suspect the crashing of your backend is unrelated to any request. But when the frontend tries to issue the CORS request, it's already crashed, thus the preflight does not succeed (as the error tells you) ...